# Query users using my app in iOS swift (Parse)

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

In my application users stores their phone number. Using the phone number I did a query that compares the phone number from address book and the phone number stored in the database (parse back-end) for match users using the app. The problem is that my table did not return any data. I did the basic configuration to request address book and table delegate functions. This is my query function:

```
import UIKit
import AddressBook
import Parse

class mainContactViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var namesTableView: UITableView!


    var addressBook: ABAddressBook!
    var names:[String]?

    func createAddressBook() {

        var error: Unmanaged<CFErrorRef>?

        addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(nil, &error).takeRetainedValue()

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.namesTableView.delegate = self
        self.namesTableView.dataSource = self

        accessAddressBook()

        self.namesTableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func accessAddressBook () {
        switch ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus(){
        case .Authorized:
            println("Already authorized")
            createAddressBook()
            beginContactSearch()
            /* Access the address book */
        case .Denied:
            println("Denied access to address book")

        case .NotDetermined:
            createAddressBook()
            if let theBook: ABAddressBookRef = addressBook{
                ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(theBook,
                    {(granted: Bool, error: CFError!) in

                        if granted{
                            println("Access granted")
                        } else {
                            println("Access not granted")
                        }

                })
            }

        case .Restricted:
            println("Access restricted")

        default:
            println("Other Problem")
            }
        }


func beginContactSearch(){
   let people = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook).takeRetainedValue() as   NSArray as [ABRecord]

            for person in people {
                // Name
                let name = ABRecordCopyCompositeName(person).takeRetainedValue()

                // Phones
                let phones: ABMultiValueRef = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty).takeRetainedValue()
                names = Array()
                for (var i = 0; i < ABMultiValueGetCount(phones); i++) {
                    let phones: String = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, i).takeRetainedValue() as String
                    var friendsquery = PFQuery(className:"_Users")
                        friendsquery.whereKey("phoneNumber" , equalTo:phones)
                        friendsquery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                            if error == nil{
                              //  if let objects = objects as? [String] {
                                    for object in objects {
                                        var phoneslist = object as NSString
                                       self.names!.append(phoneslist)

                                    }
                                //}
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                    self.namesTableView.reloadData()
            }

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.names?.count ?? 0
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = namesTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Tablecell") as UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel!.text = names![indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        return cell
    }


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I´m sorry, I need to guess what is the error because its hard to find it without the project... :-)

try to exchange the code in your file with the code under this line

```
friendsquery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
   if error == nil{
      for object in objects! {
         if let phoneslist: NSString = object as? NSString {
            self.names!.append(phoneslist)
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Ok, my first guess was right :-) So let me try another one...

In this code:

```
if let phoneslist: NSString = object as? NSString {
   self.names!.append(phoneslist)
}
```

You try to cast object as NSString... Well I don't know Parse and I don´t know how their objects are build, but you need to do something like this...

```
if let phoneslist: PFObject = object as? PFObject {
   if let nameFromList: NSString = phoneslist["name"] as? NSString {
       self.names!.append(nameFromList)
   }
}
```

I guess that PFObject is an object holding multiple values... So you have to also define which of that values you want by its key...

So you need to NSLog object to get its keys, and after that you change the code to my new code above and you are done

Comment: Please try this and write me if the error occurs anyway

Comment: Hello @Neo , I changed my code and did not work (It didn't give me any warning). I updated my code with the address book and table delegate functions.

Comment: Well what happened? If it didn't give you a warning, the error should be solved?!? :-) Have you checked if var phoneslist = object as NSString your object are castable to NSString? Or what kind of Data is object representing? Maybe you can't cast object to NSString, so my code above is right, but you have to alter the object as NSString part :-)

Comment: It didn't give me any warning, but the table view still not showing the contacts using the app. Since the var phonelist will return the parse query, I changed my var to PFObject (var phonelist = object as? [PFObject] ). When I try to compile  now it shows: "PFObject is not convertible to NSString" on the append line.

Comment: Yes thats what I thought... I will write you an update